# Use CustomScrollView contains BackdropFilter ,Why the whole screen has been blurred

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in Flutter.
When Widget appeard like the screenshot_1,The whole screen has been blurred,
however,Where scroll to the position,the BackdropFilter disappered.
I just want the header background to be blurred. Please help me, thanks.
If there was some better suggestion,Please share them,that would be helpful to me.

[image]
[image]

Here's the code

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:demo/model/PoolDetailModel.dart';
import 'package:demo/utils/Utils.dart';
import 'package:extended_image/extended_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PoolDetailView extends StatefulWidget {
  final PoolDetailModel model;

  PoolDetailView({this.model});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PoolDetailViewState(model: model);
}

class PoolDetailViewState extends State<PoolDetailView> {
  final PoolDetailModel model;
  PoolDetailViewState({this.model});
  double headerHeight = 190;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: mainView(),
      navigationBar: getNavigationBar(),
    );
  }

  CupertinoNavigationBar getNavigationBar() {
    return CupertinoNavigationBar(
      transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
      heroTag: model.hashCode.toString(),
      middle: Text("详情"),
    );
  }

  Widget mainView() {
    return SafeArea(child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child:headerView()
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child:bodyView()
        )
      ],
    )
    );
    // return SafeArea(child: Column(children: [headerView(), bodyView()]));
  }

  Widget headerView() {
    var url = Utils.convertUrl(model.posts[0].jpegUrl);
    return Container(
      child: Stack(children: [
        ExtendedImage.network(
          url,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: headerHeight,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
        blurLayer(),
        Center(
            child: Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              child: roundImage(url, 100, 150),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Padding(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    model.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 3,
                  ),
                  Container(height: 10),
                  ratingLable(),
                  Container(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    "共 " + model.postCount.toString() + " 页",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 8, bottom: 10, left: 15),
            ))
          ],
        )),
      ]),
      height: headerHeight,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    );
  }

  Widget ratingLable() {
    String rate = "S";
    Color color = Colors.blueGrey;
    for (var item in model.posts) {
      if (item.rating == "E") {
        rate = "E";
        color = Colors.redAccent;
        break;
      } else if (item.rating == "Q") {
        rate = "Q";
        color = Colors.yellowAccent;
        break;
      }
    }

    return ClipRRect(
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(rate,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        height: 18,
        width: 18,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color),
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
    );
  }

  Widget blurLayer() {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6, sigmaY: 6),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
        height: headerHeight,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget roundImage(String url, double width, double height) {
    return Container(
      child: ClipRRect(
        child: ExtendedImage.network(
          url,
          width: width,
          height: height,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          blurRadius: 5,
          offset: Offset(0, 0),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget bodyView() {
    return Container(
        child: ExtendedImage.network(Utils.convertUrl(model.posts[0].jpegUrl),
            fit: BoxFit.cover));
  }
}
```